# The notation $A^{\text{cop}}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras, coalgebras

Let $A$ be an algebra. Then $A^{\text{op}}$ is the algebra with multiplication defined by $a \cdot b = b \circ a$, where $b \circ a$ is the multiplication in $A$.

Let $A$ be a coalgebra. How to define the comultiplication in $A^{\text{cop}}$? Thank you very much.

Comment: May be help http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43382/how-to-work-with-co-multiplication

Comment: Please tell me there is an algebra called $\bf Robo$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you work over a commutative ring $R$.

Then, multiplication is a map from the tensor product $\mu:A\otimes A\to A$, satisfying associativity. Its opposite is defined as the composition $\mu\circ\sigma$ where $\sigma:A\otimes A\to A\otimes A$ is the exchange $a\otimes b\mapsto b\otimes a$.

Now, comultiplication is a map to the tensor product $\Delta:A\to A\otimes A$ (satisfying coassociativity), and thus its opposite should be the composition $\sigma\circ\Delta$.

Comment: I think that you need the $A$ is  co-commutative

Comment: @Deliasaghi, thank you very much. Where is the property that $A$ is cocommutative used?

Comment: Dear @LJR sorry I'm not sure, I remember that a coalgebra  is called co-commutative if $\sigma\circ\Delta=\Delta$.

Comment: @Deliasaghi, thank you very much.

Comment: @ Deliasaghi: no, it is not true that you need $A$ to be cocommutative. The definition of the cooposite coalgebra is valid for any coalgebra. In case it is, then $A$ and $A^{cop}$ coincide (in the same sense that a commutative algebra coincides with its opposite algebra).

Comment: In general, if $\mathsf C$ is a monoidal category that is braided, one can define (co)commutativity in terms of the braid (in this case the braid is the 'obvious' braid that exchanges the factors).